# Why can't I comment on this answer?

Tags: support, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Here is a question with some answers:

[Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio)

I want to ask Lou Franco to clarify his answer by commenting on his answer. However, I can't comment — in fact, I see no way to comment on any of the answers to this question.

Why?

And how should I request clarifications when I can't comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you need [50 rep to leave comments on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

Note that the [rep thresholds on meta.stackoverflow are different.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Comment: And how should I get the clarification of an answer if I can't comment? I guess if I don't have 50 reputation then I just have to ask a new question?

Comment: note that IF YOU OWN AN ANSWER OR QUESTION you can comment on it with 1 rep. (and if you own the question, you can comment on any answers to that question too, even with 1 rep)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a certain (50) threshold of reputation before you can comment..

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I definitely understand the reason for the threshold approach but I would like to suggest that lowering the threshold for comments would cut down on the answers that just represent minor tweaks to existing answers.

Comment: I definitely agree with this. While looking for an answer to a question I also had, I've found it on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395702/migrating-from-svn-to-perforce-tips-experience. User Paul Ruane commented that he had improved the script and I would have liked to comment that I'm interested in it, too! But I cannot!...

Comment: How the hell do they expect us to answer questions (to get more reputation) if we can't even ask for clarifications..Then if we ask questions in the "answer" part we get downvoted..

Comment: @user1227197: Just point out in your answer that you don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: oh thank you a bunch!

Comment: I definitely agree with the critizism though... I often see answers that are technically correct but e.g. slightly outdated regarding coding conventions. Considering the rule "But avoid [...] Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers." I can't see how I should do this, when I can't comment. Considering that the contents fitting into a comment require less knowledge than those applicable to a separate answer, the current reputations system seems somewhat upside-down.

Comment: Reputation is another word for acceptance/trust here on stackoverflow. I'm not saying that's good or bad... but it is the way things work.. and fighting it is harder than gaining the rep... IMO, YMMD

Comment: I am not sure if I'll ever gain any rep, so that I can post comments, because most of the problems I get in my development are either already asked/answered. Thanks for clarifying though.

Comment: You're at the whim of high reputation users.  They down vote you enough, and now, you just lost all your privileges to comment and up/downvote.  May as well... I spend too much time online anyways.  I'll just come to SE to copy snippets of code, and that's it.